Why is my variable not been checked in sonarqube even though value is assigned inside catch block
consider an example
public static boolean MyFunction() {
boolean isReturnNull = false;
try{
//some code
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  //dosomething & log errors if needed
  isReturnNull = true;
}
if(isReturnNull == true)
{
  return null;
}
else
{
  //return something;
}

my Sonarqube return with this critical error saying this will always be evaluated as false in the above segment pasting it below again.
{
  return null;
}

Question is why isn't it checking the catch block which has it value changed to true.
Kindly help on this why its happening, sorry forgot to mention its written in JAVA code.

Please provide a [MRE]. I suspect that the variable isReturnNull is never set to false, or that the else-path may return a null as well (maybe on a not so trivial to see way).

Separately, the general principle of "Do stuff, if an exception is thrown, take all the relevant data that the exception contains about what happens, throw it in the garbage and just return null" is deplorably bad code in 99 out of a 100 times I have seen it. If you're gonna go with 'yeah but it works for me', that's great, you do you, but then also using sonarqube is ridiculous.

Have corrected the default initialization of the boolean value, its set as false by default & then in catch block its changed, And yes its something Sonarqube is ignoring the catch block
